# QML : How to read a QList from C++

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qml

I have a simple need : I have defined a C++ class

```
class MyClass: public QDeclarativeItem
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MyClass(QDeclarativeItem * parent=0);
    ...

  private:
    QList<QString> mList
}
```

And of course, I've registered it : `qmlRegisterType<MyClass>(...)`

I want to access in the QML code to my `QList<QString> mList`. How can I do it?

It annoys me as it looks like a simple problem, but I can't find anything about this. (I can create a Q_INVOKABLE slot, but I can't read the results, etc...)

Edit : [QML supported Data Types](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtbinding.html#supported-data-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that `QList` is a supported data type for Qt's QML binding.  I've had similar problems interfacing between C++ and JavaScript using the QtWebkit Bridge.

If possible, try using a `QVariantList` instead of a `QList`.  Although this is technically a typedef for `QList<QVariant>` I think it should work.

Comment: According to this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html `QList C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML as JavaScript Array types`

Answer (score 2):

If you need a custom type in your list (not just strings or other basic types) there's QDeclarativeListProperty for that case.

But it's more complicated, see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/declarative-tutorials-extending-chapter5-listproperties.html