# QJSEngine vs QtScript and QList<MyClass>

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript, qjsengine

Since `Qt` 5.5 is actual, `QtScript` is deprecated. The replacement is `Qt` QML with [`QJSEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html). Now, I will rewrite my project to the new engine. I have some Classes like:

```
class Node : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Node*> childs READ childs)

public:
    inline QList<Node*> childs() {
        return childsByID.values();
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QList<Node*> someChilds(QString filter);
    Q_INVOKABLE Node* makeChild(/*some args*/); // returns maybe 0.

private:
    Node(Node* parent);

    QHash<QString, Node*> childsByID;
    QHash<QString, Node*> childsByXYZ;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Node*)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<Node*>)
```

and in `QtScript` registered this with:

```
qScriptRegisterMetaType(&engine, nodeToScriptValue, nodeFromScriptValue);
qScriptRegisterSequenceMetaType<QList<Node*>>(&engine);
```

In the new QJSEngine I register the Node with qmlRegisterUncreatableType. But, I don't find a way to register the QList.

Knows anybody the right way ?

Comment: @hellofunk says "QList C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML as JavaScript Array types" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438157/qml-how-to-read-a-qlist-from-c

Comment: No, only for QVariantList (QList<QVariant>) but I don't have a copy-constructor im my class witch is neeted to copy to QVariant. I don't like to copy all my QHash'es and other Vars.

Comment: I didn't think qobjects were copied because they're based on smart pointers. Sorry that did not work.